# Is there a way to get UNIX to help utilize GPU usage for python execution

Tags: python, unix, gpu

I am trying to run python experiment with different argument on GPU. For example,

```
python experiment.py --arg1 10 &
python experiment.py --arg1 15 &
python experiment.py --arg1 20 &
```

each will take different memory usage. For example, "python experiment.py --arg1 10 &" might take 100 MB of memory. "python experiment.py --arg1 15 &" might take 200 MB.

What I had to do is that I have to estimate how much I can use for each process and put the command wait in unix shell script until the process is done.

```
python experiment.py --arg1 10 &
pid1 = $! 
python experiment.py --arg1 15 &
pid2 = $!
python experiment.py --arg1 20 &
pid3 = $!
wait $pid1 $pid2 $pid3
python experiment.py --arg1 50 &
pid1 = $!
python experiment.py --arg1 35 &
pid2 = $!
python experiment.py --arg1 10 &
pid3 = $!
wait $pid1 $pid2 $pid3
```

but by doing this I cannot fully utilize the GPU memory since I have to approximate roughly on memory usage and if I put to much process on running, some process will exit without calculation and I have to revise which one is missing after the whole process is done.

**Is there a command in UNIX that can dynamically determine the memory freed on GPU and sequentially initialize the process once there is some space available?**

Thanks